# What is the max file size to open a KMZ* in Google Earth

Tags: kml, tiff, google-earth, kmz

I am working with orthomosaics in TIF format and I convert them to KMZ* files for Google Earth.
The problem is the resolution of the image, when it is very high, I have 2 gb KMZ* and it doesn't open in Google Earth. It opens the program but doesn't load anything. I solved it by lowing the resolution to have projects around 200 mb so Google Earth can read them, the problem is that by doing this, I *lose* resolution.
So, to minimize my losses, does anyone know the maximum KMZ* file size that Google Earth can read and load?

Comment: KMJ? - do you mean a KML or KMZ file? Also, are you running Google Earth on Windows OS?

Comment: KMZ! Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Your limit is likely not the file size (though 2gb is pretty massive), but rather the image size in pixels. The maximum image size you can load into Earth for an Overlay is based on the capabilities of your computer's graphics card. If you go to Help >> About Google Earth (somewhere else on Mac), you'll see a line about "Max Texture Size", which indicates this limit.  Most are 4096x4096 or 8192x8192, though some are lower and some are higher. So you can bring in an image up to that size on your machine, but a machine with a weaker graphics card may not be able to render the same image.

You have a few options.  As others have suggested, I would try Google Earth Pro (now free for everyone), which can import a very large image, and will give you options to crop it, down-res it, or create a superoverlay. You can also turn your image into a KML superoverlay with other 3rd party tools.  A superoverlay is a KML structure that allows you to load a tiled version of your image, so that it shows a few tiles at low resolutions, and loads just the tiles it needs for your current view area at higher resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth is a 32-bit application and is limited to 2GB memory and a 2GB disk cache. Google Earth itself needs memory set aside for the app, base imagery, and layers leaving the rest for user-defined KML and KMZ files. Note KMZ files are unpacked and loaded into memory so it's the unpacked file size that is the limit not the compressed KMZ file size. You can streamline Google Earth with more memory for user-defined files if you turn off all layers and other saved places. There are some tips to [manage your saved places](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#Managing_Places). But very large files will still need to be reduced in size one way or another.

For large GeoTIFFs files, [Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/download/gep/agree.html) has an option to create a super overlay and a series of KML and image tiles which change resolution when you zoom in & out. Simply drag the TIF file onto Google Earth map after which you will be prompted to create a "Super Overlay". Pick a directory where the generated files will be created and wait for the conversion. Depending on the size it may take a couple of minutes. It will create a root KML and possibly 1000s of linked KMZ files each with a PNG or JPEG image tile.